# I'm having trouble with dragging a div inside of a TD

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have the following structure:

```
<td class=\"dropbears\">
<div class=\"thingtodrag\" style=\"display:block; width:100px;\"></div>
</td>
```

I have a bunch of other tds that are empty but have space.
And I have a declaration of draggable and droppable:

```
$(".thingtodrag").draggable();
$(".dropbears").droppable({
    accept:"thingtodrag",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.draggable.appendTo($(this).css({
        top: "0.2em",
        left: "0.2em"
      }));
    }
});
```

No matter what I do, though, I can't click the div to drag it (it does not respond).  If I make the td draggable, it can be dragged, but then I end up with tds inside tds and issues with dropping the item in the right location, so I'm really hoping to make the div draggable.  Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a closing parenthesis after the `appendTo` statement. `Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.`

Comment: @showdev Fixed the typo, was just a typo on code transcription and sanitation, I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to drag `<div>`!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
     var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
     dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
   });
     $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
     if (event.type === 'drop') {
     var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
     if($(this).find('span').length===0){
       de=$('#'+data).detach();
       de.appendTo($(this)); 
      }
    
     };
    });
})
```

```css
table th,table td{
 height: 30px;
 width: 200px;
 
}
table div{
 display:block;
 background-color: #17A7C6;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="event" id="a" draggable="true">AAA</div></td>
        <td><div class="event" id="b" draggable="true">BBB</div></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It was just syntax error in the code.

Comment: Your example does not append the div to the TDs when the div is dropped inside the TDs - though the div is clickable, when mine is not.  Interesting.

Comment: @Kwahn code is now changed, not drag and drop both events are working. I hope this is the answer you want, thanks

Comment: Totally is - I had been missing the dataTransfer event bit.  Thank you!